# Devise routing error "No route matches [GET] " for all routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, rails-routing

I recently installed devise (migrated from restful authorization), and when I tried to check the site, I got the following error `No route matches [GET] "/"`, this error came for every URL I tried. 
Here is my rake routes data

```
   new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                       devise/sessions#new
              user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                       devise/sessions#create
      destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                      devise/sessions#destroy
             user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#create
         new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                  devise/passwords#new
        edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                 devise/passwords#edit
                           PUT    /users/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#update
  cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                        devise/registrations#cancel
         user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#create
     new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                       devise/registrations#new
    edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                          devise/registrations#edit
                           PUT    /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#update
                           DELETE /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#destroy
                   session POST   /session(.:format)                             sessions#create
               new_session GET    /session/new(.:format)                         sessions#new
                           DELETE /session(.:format)                             sessions#destroy
                    signup        /signup(.:format)                              users#new
                  register        /register(.:format)                            users#create
                     login        /login(.:format)                               sessions#new
                    logout        /logout(.:format)                              sessions#destroy
                  activate        /activate/:activation_code(.:format)           users#activate {:activation_code=>nil}
#more routing
```

This is my routes file

```
dminStagingPuzzleflowUs::Application.routes.draw do
     devise_for :users

#resources :users

resource :session, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]

match 'signup' => 'users#new', :as => :signup

match 'register' => 'users#create', :as => :register

match 'login' => 'sessions#new', :as => :login

match 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout

  match '/activate/:activation_code' => 'users#activate', :as => :activate,                   :activation_code => nil

#The priority is based upon order of creation:
# first created -> highest priority.


#resource :sessions
resources :support_issues
#other resources 

match '' => 'home#index', :as => :home
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))'


  root to: 'home#index'

end
```

If you need anything else please let me know. Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was a server restart. Apparently since Devise affects routing this should be done after setting it up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your `routes.rb`

```
 dminStagingPuzzleflowUs::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]

  devise_scope :user do
    match 'signup' => 'users#new', :as => :signup
    match 'register' => 'users#create', :as => :register
    match 'login' => 'sessions#new', :as => :login
    match 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
  end

  match '/activate/:activation_code' => 'users#activate', :as => :activate,  :activation_code => nil

  #The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.
  #resource :sessions

  resources :support_issues
  #other resources 


  root to: 'home#index'
end
```

and run `rake routes`

Comment: In response to the edit. Removing the `match '' => 'home#index', :as => :home
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))'` does not the rake routes or routing error either.

Comment: are you serious `routing error “No route matches [GET]` for all url? tried remove all route for devise on your `routes.rb` and see what will happen.

Comment: I am indeed serious. When I remove the devise lines from the routing error I get `undefined method 'authenticate_user!' for ` errors.

Comment: On the url. `NoMethodError in HomeController#index
undefined method 'authenticate_user!' for #<HomeController:0x000000039eed98>` It is the same for other pages, just a different name for the controller. That method was also never in the controller. \

Comment: remove `before_filter :authenticate_user!` on `homes_controller.rb`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30576/discussion-between-btuman-and-anonymousxxx)